# CSS HTML overflow issue with static header in wrap

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with the bottom part of the overflowing content as can be seen in the fiddle. How would you go about fixing this, while keeping this layout?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sa6cb/392/

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrappedheader {
  position: static;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 15px;
}

.wrappedbody {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;  
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrappedheader">
    This is a header
  </div>

  <div class="wrappedbody">
    <!-- Content causing overflow-y -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Struggling in what way? Are you trying to make the scrollbar entirely visible? If so, the answer is http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Sa6cb/396/

Comment: Thanks, this did it. Edit: Not sure if I understand it though, why are we subtracting exactly 61px? And isn't there a more robust way that don't use calculations that would work?

Comment: Paddings. 15px times 4. See also @feihcsim's answer. Gotta go now, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Your wrappedbody has height 100%, which is 100% of its parent, wrapper. However, wrapper has two children, wrappedbody *and* wrappedheader. The height of wrappedbody should be the height of wrapper minus the height of wrappedheader:

```
.wrappedbody {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 79px); /* 79 = wrappedheader height + wrappedbody padding*/
    padding: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/feihcsim/14auqpqd/

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the header height is dynamically changing in my problem, so I don't know the height of it.

Comment: Then move the height constraint from wrapper to wrappedbody
http://jsfiddle.net/feihcsim/14auqpqd/1/

Comment: The wrappedbody div will also have dynamic height, but I guess I can work with it for now. Thanks!

Comment: Wait! If you don't want to worry about compatibility with older browsers, check out one of CSS's cooler new features, [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). (Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/feihcsim/14auqpqd/2/)

Comment: Very cool. I think this is exactly what I need, although copy pasting the demo solution gave some weird results for my real problem. Will read up on it, thanks again!